# Would putting vitamin pills in a blender alter their effectiveness?

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients

Vitamin pills are usually taken orally or sublingually. If I crush them inside a blender as a part of a shake, would it compromise their function?

Answer (score 3):

Only a study in which someone would put different vitamins in a blender and measure the eventual changes in their activities could answer this question. Everything else is just a guess or estimation.

Next, the question would need to be for a specific vitamin in a specific chemical form and in a specific tablet.

My estimation is that nothing significant would happen. Some vitamins could be partly destroyed by heat, but blending alone does not produce much heat, anyway. Crushing of the tablet could affect the physical composition of the tablet and result in either slightly decreased or increased absorption of the vitamin.

On [NutritionData](http://nutritiondata.self.com/topics/processing), there is a chart with estimated effects of drying, cooking and freezing on the vitamin content of foods. For example, cooking (it does not say for how long) can destroy 25% of vitamin A, 50% of vitamin C and 70% of folic acid.

I think, in general, blending would not do nearly as much damage as cooking.

Answer (score 1):

From a chemical point of view, no. Vitamins are fairly stable molecules, so they can live into acidic media (like lemon, vitamin C) or other life media which are generally not prone for chemical species stability.

Avoid heating though, this *will* alter them.

Comment: What's wrong with freezing?

Comment: Nothing, edited to check error.

Comment: This post has the makings of a very good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)

Comment: I agree that we need references on Health. However, those are simply basic rules of chemistry. Any undergrad chemistry student can confirm what I said here. About freezing, I asked on chemistry StackExchange in order to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Your answer is true, but misleading. Just because the vitamins are not changed, there is no guarantee that they will have the same effect as when taken as whole tablets, because the way something is metabolised depends on microstructure, not just on content.

Comment: I edited your post to correct what I think was a minor translation error. If you disagree with my edit, you can revert it.

Comment: Another factor that is worth considering is that particles/molecules in solution may partly adsorb to the sides of the container (due to equal distribution throughout the solution and specific chemical properties of the molecules and container). Unless you scrape the sides of the blender completely, you are most likely to lose some of the material, which may compromise the dose you were planning on getting from the tablet. For further information regarding the effects of crushing tablets in general, see [here](https://www.rpharms.com/support-pdfs/pharmaceuticalissuesdosageformsjune-2011.pdf).

Comment: @Don_S I absolutely agree. In any kind of preparation, one would lose some quantity that would stay in the leftover juice, or as you say, on blender's sides. One should beware not to add too much more though (especially if hydrophobic vitamins are concerned).

Comment: One way to overcome this potential loss is to rinse the container's sides with a little water and drink it (will work better with water-soluble vitamins than with fat-soluble vitamins).  Another way is to just swallow the tablet as is (if there are no swallowing problems) and be done with it...